# User-defined functions in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to define a user function in `vim` to change the current color scheme, then override some of the theme's settings to make it work better with my transparent terminal configuration. I can't seem to find any info on how to call `set` lines inside of a function.

This conveys what I'd like to accomplish:

```
function SetColorscheme (colorscheme)
  set colorscheme a:colorscheme
  hi Normal ctermbg=NONE
  hi LineNr ctermbg=NONE
endfunction
```

And I'm currently calling it like this:

```
:call SetColorscheme ('wombat256')
```

Currently `vim` is complaining about missing parentheses.

What's the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`colorscheme` is *not* an option you use with the set command, it's a command of its own.  So try this for the colorscheme line:

```
execute 'colorscheme ' . a:colorscheme
```

Comment: Nice--thanks. First time through I missed the space after `colorscheme`. :) I need to tackle `vim` scripting, but right now I'm hip deep in `node.js` and `backbone.js`... Only so much bandwidth to go around.